# Get a callback when jQuery.queue() is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, queue, delay

I'm trying to receive a callback from a queue. I want to call a function when the queue is done. How can this be done? (I've been searching the net for a while now, without success)

```
divs.each(function (index) {
    var thisDiv = $(this);
    var thisDelay = 75 * index;

    thisDiv.delay(thisDelay).queue(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });

    // For example 'return: true' / call a new function.
});
```

Thanks